# Mejorar eficiencia del codigo

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, revisión-de-código

Hay alguna manera de mejorar este código? Para que no haga mas de una consulta?

```
Comando = "Select * from TClientes, TContratosClubes, TAgentes where 
TContratosClubes.idcontrato = '" & idcontrato & "' and 
TContratosClubes.idCliente = TClientes.idCliente and TAgentes.idAgente = 
TContratosClubes.idAgente"

While oDataReader.Read()
    numCedula.Text = oDataReader("cedulaCliente")
    nombre.Text = oDataReader("nombreCliente")
    numCliente = oDataReader("idCliente")
    msExito.Text = "Registro encontrados exitosamente!"
    listaContratos.Items.Add(oDataReader("idContrato"))
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(oDataReader("idContrato"))
    numContrato.Text = oDataReader("idContrato")
    numCliente = oDataReader("idCliente")
    Serie.Text = oDataReader("serieContrato")
    Numero.Text = oDataReader("numeroContrato")
    Agentes = oDataReader("idAgente")
    sumaTotal = oDataReader("cuotasInicio")
    PrimerSorteo.Text = oDataReader("fechaPrimerSorteo")
    MontoCuotas.Text = oDataReader("montoCuotaContrato")
    If MontoCuotas.Text > 55 Then
        dolarColon.Text = "₡"
        dolarColon0.Text = "₡"
    Else
        dolarColon.Text = "$"
        dolarColon0.Text = "$"
    End If

    MontoUtilizar.Text = MontoCuotas.Text * 91
    Agente.Text = oDataReader("nombreAgente")
    apeAgente.Text = oDataReader("apellidosAgente")
End While
oDataReader.Close()
numCedula.Focus()
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total = "SELECT SUM(cantidadCuotas) AS suma  FROM TPagosCuotas where idContrato = '" & numContrato.Text & "'"
Dim tot As New SqlCommand(Total, cadena)
oDataReader = tot.ExecuteReader()
While oDataReader.Read
    cantidadCuotas.Text = oDataReader("suma")
    cantidadCuotas.Text = sumaTotal + cantidadCuotas.Text
End While
oDataReader.Close()
```

Comment: me preocuparía primero de evitar sql injection

Comment: En tu código solo indicas una sola consulta `SELECT SUM(cantidadCuotas) AS suma  FROM TPagosCuotas`, ¿Dónde está las demás consultas?. Recuerda que puedes [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/93895/edit) para que agregues más detalle. https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/93895/edit

Comment: Listo ya lo cambie

Comment: si pero agregaste otro query y no explicaste nada de lo que hace. Si quieres que revisemos tu codigo, necesitamos saber que revisar, el modelo de datos. Todo lo necesario para que mirandolo nos demos cuenta de los problemas...

Comment: Hay varias maneras de optimizar el codigo, pero sin saber exactamente que hace es dificil concretar. Crea una clase cuyas propiedades sean los datos que quieres guardar. Con Entity Framework o Linq-To-Sql haces el query y guardas la respuesta en una instancia de la clase que creaste. Ahora puedes utilizar databindings para presentar los datos en la UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si Sr, puedes incluir la segunda consulta dentro de la primera utilizando una subconsulta así:

```
Comando = "Select * from TClientes, TContratosClubes, TAgentes, 
(
    SELECT SUM(cantidadCuotas) AS suma  FROM TPagosCuotas where idContrato = 
        '" & idcontrato & "'
) as suma 
where TContratosClubes.idcontrato = '" & idcontrato & "' 
    and TContratosClubes.idCliente = TClientes.idCliente 
    and TAgentes.idAgente = TContratosClubes.idAgente"
```